# TFS Failing Queue New Build With Shelveset

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am trying to build our solution with help of the build server.
When i queue a build normally with on the definition, the build succeeds and everything is fine. If i try to queue a build with a shelveset, then the build fails with the following message: "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets (3102): Invalid value for 'AssemblyVersion'."

I have tried searching here on stack overflow and on the net, but haven't been able to find anything on "Invalid value for 'AssemblyVersion'" and what could be causing it.

The shelveset is actually an empty selveset only containing a whitespace in one of the files.

Comment: What build process template are you using?

Comment: Has your build template been customised in any way? Maybe a "private build" doesn't set "assembly version" parameter you have.